# Ubuntu One notifications?

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator, notify-osd, messaging-menu

Is it possible to somehow setup Ubuntu One to get notifications when something is updated.

Example:

Synced:

```
/home/user/workspace/xxx.py  
/home/user/workspace/ggg.py  
/home/user/workspace/UUU.py
```

Synced notes:

```
mynote1
```

Synced:

```
Nothing new so nothing synced.
```

Synced notes:
Nothing new so nothing synced.

I restarted as suggested after installing indicator, but still can't see it in applet list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu One Indicator by opening the Terminal (Applications>Accessories> Terminal) and enter the following lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-indicator
```

[image]

Credit for the image: [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-gets-a-ppa/)

Currently the PPA is available for Lucid and Maverick users only.

Comment: I installed it, but i dont see it in applet list, how to proceed? Looks like i need to restart, i will try that first.

Comment: Yeah. Try that, the OMG! article doesn't give better install instructions, so you need to test and report.

Comment: Actually it's a bug: http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/660002